# TikZ manual newest version online?

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation

Is there a definite place where TikZ manual can be found online?

I am only finding version 2.00, while I keep loosing the link to 2.10.

Does the [official site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/?_test=b) host the manual somewhere, or is it only available in the zip? Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.0/

Comment: @peterGrill the link you posted no longer works!

Comment: @PauloNey: The one linked to in my answer below seems to work. Better still, just us `texdoc pgf` or `texdoc tikz` on the command line (assuming you have access to a terminal shell).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The latest **officialy** released manual would be at [the PGF site of the Comprehensive TEX Archive Network (CTAN)](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or directly at https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

If you need **the absolute most recent version** or **previous versions** of the manual (even unstable builds of PGF/TikZ), then you can look at [the list of releases](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases) in [the GitHub source repository](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf) (the PDFs are under the ▶ **Assets** collapsible item).

Comment: For the most current manual, this is the best answer. The version there is more recent than all the other answers (by 3 weeks as I post this comment), and it's a direct link to a PDF (not buried in an archive.)

Comment: Changing the accepted answer to this. Since the stable version is outdated (at this time) http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf this is better.

Answer (score 43):

The place to look for the PGF offical released manual would be the [CTAN directory: ctan.org/pkg/pgf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: That one is from `2010-10-25`.  Is that really the latest?

Comment: As of today, the [CTAN link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf) is pointing to the 2.10 of the manual, while version 3.0.0 of the manual is available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/).

Comment: CTAN does not hold the latest version, sourceforge does, the manual is zipped as far as I can tell, inside the doc directory: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.0/

Comment: @PatrickT: Yes, the link in this answer is for the "official released" manual.

Answer (score 24):

You could also use the web site that [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz) and [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda) recently put together. Just enter

```
http://texdoc.net/pkg/<packagename>
```

into your browser's address field and you'll automatically be taken to the right place. So in your case, go to http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz  or http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf, they both lead to the manual, version 2.10.

Joseph Wright wrote about this service on our blog: [TeX documentation online: texdoc.net](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/tex-documentation-online-texdoc-net/)

Comment: Amazing, how come I never knew about this before damn it.

Comment: FWIW, entering `texdoc pgf` on the command line will open your locally installed PGF manual, too.

Comment: @drozzy Well, it's just a week or two since texdoc.net was launched.

Comment: @user946850 FWIT = For What It's Worth. Was that so hard? Also, I'm getting "No viewer associated with this file type" error in windows... :-(

Comment: @doncherry: If, oh, only if - there was a "UI" page, that allowed one to enter a package name into the form; then this site could actually be indexed by google!

Comment: @drozzy: Try `texdoc -l pgf`. What does it say?

Comment: @drozzy: There is! Check out http://www.texdoc.net/.

Comment: texdoc.net does not give us the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a CVS version of pgf tikz, I put on my site [altermundus](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html) the complete archive with the documentation and the changelog (it's the version of 24/01:2012) I will put the last one in a few days.

Comment: That is pretty cool! However, I use Miketex - which gets this stuff for me automagically; also I don't want to have different versions running on different machines.

Comment: You can look only at the new pgfmanual to see what will be the future !

Answer (score 4):

The source for this package is on Github (Aug 16, 2019). The manual is created as part of the continuous integration process and uploaded to:
https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019, the documentation (manual) version 3.1.1 can be found in pdf form at: [CTAN-math-washington-edu: TikZ & PGF](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). It's north of 1200 pages, so I suppose this is the *complete manual*.

Comment: Generic url: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf (http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)