# What is a suitable package for drawing term algebra style trees

Tags: trees, technical-drawing

I want to be able to draw something like nested triangles that are arranged in a tree-like fashion.  Or explicitly, a node of a tree is represented as an isosceles triangle pointed upward.  Each subtree should be drawn as a subtriangle.

Here is an image

[image]

Are there any nice packages for doing things like this?  Or should I use a geometry drawing package.

Comment: The [`tikz` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49698/tikz-manual-newest-version-online) is what I would recommend.

Comment: Thank you, I added an image.

I was discussing Tikz with a few people this morning, and I had gotten the impression that is not user friendly.  Would you suggest that in fact, Tikz is easy to use?

Comment: Tikz will have hiccups in the beginning. But you know it will be a starting trouble which goes off slowly. If you are after drawing software you can look at `inkscape` (http://inkscape.org/) of `geogebra` (http://www.geogebra.org/cms/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have commented, [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) can be an option. In the following example I used the `isosceles triangle` shape from the `shapes` library and defined the `\MyTr` command with three mandatory arguments (name, minimum height, and position of the triangle). Of course, this is just to show one possibility, but you can change and adapt the code depending on your specific needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\definecolor{tblue}{RGB}{207,232,229}

\newcommand\MyTr[3]{%
  \node[isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=70,
    draw, inner sep=0pt,anchor=lower side,rotate=90,draw=black,
    fill=tblue, minimum height=#2 cm] (#1) at #3 {};
  \fill (#1.apex) -- (#1.20) -- (#1.340) -- cycle;}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\MyTr{a}{8}{(0,0)}
\MyTr{b}{2.5}{(-2.5,0)}
\MyTr{c}{2.5}{(2.5,0)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  It looks like Tikz is certainly a reasonable solution.  I will look into it.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher: you're welcome! If my response answers your question, please consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking the tickmark below its vote count.

Comment: Do you know of documentation for tikz where things like apex are defined.  I did not see it in the manual by Tantau for example.

Comment: @JonathanGallagher: the anchors for the `isosceles triangle` shape appear in a diagram in page 429 of the [current CTAN version of the pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).