# PGF manual 3.0.1a permalink

Tags: tikz-pgf, links, documentation

I was wondering whether anyone knows of a permalink to the current version of the pgf manual. I am cross referencing links from my package documentation to the tikz manual and would like to make sure that the links don't end up going to the wrong section of an updated version of the tikz manual, but also don't want to link an old version.

Comment: What do you mean by not wanting to link an old version? If the manual is updated, a permalink will be to an old version, won't it?

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: @percusse Well, that's the same as for CarLaTeX. It doesn't link to a specific version, but to the manual in general.

Comment: I suppose it's almost a duplicate of mine https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294476/is-there-a-tikz-and-pgfplot-html-manual-online ... unfortunately, seems that there are no "permalinks". Having something similar to the python documentation tree would be very nice indeed, but it's a **lot** of work.

Comment: @cfr I mean I don't want to link to an older version than the current one. By googling, I've found what appear to be permalinks to versions prior to 3.0.1a.

Comment: Previous versions are not stored. So make sure your links mention the version of the manual. Otherwise it's a disservice to whomever you are directing

Comment: I guess I have the option of hosting a copy of the manual and linking to my copy. That might be the best bet.

Comment: Version 3.0.1 is archived on SourceForge.  Unfortunately, the PDF is inside the ZIP file.  https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.1/

Comment: This is a terrible idea. What if the people using your package have a newer version of PGF and things have changed?

Comment: @cfr That's a good point. I guess that my idea was that it's better to have references to the correct section of the manual in the old version and a note that the linked manual is slightly out of date than incorrect links to the new one -- at least then it's clear where I was trying to link. This would all be fixed if latex used the labels to make logical links like "file.pdf#dash-patterns" instead of "file.pdf#section.9".